# How to visualize features classified by tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm running the default **classify_image** code of the imagenet model. Is there any way to visualize the features that it has extracted? If I use **'pool_3:0'**, that gives me the feature vector. Is there any way to overlay this on top of my image to see which features it has picked as important?

Answer (score 1):

Ross Girshick described one way to visualize what a pooling layer has learned: https://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~rbg/papers/r-cnn-cvpr.pdf

Essentially instead of visualizing features, you find a few images that a neuron fires most on. You repeat that for a few or all neurons from your feature vector. The algorithm needs lots of images to choose from of course, e.g. the test set.

I wrote my implementation of this idea for `cifar10` model in Tensorflow today, which I want to share (uses OpenCV): https://gist.github.com/kukuruza/bb640cebefcc550f357c

You could use it if you manage to provide the `images` tensor for reading images by batches, and the `pool_3:0` tensor.